# Deleting rows UItableview iphone using userdefaults

Tags: iphone, nsuserdefaults, delete-row

I need your help, maybe its something silly but I can't find the error.
I have a table view and an add button, when its clicked I show a modal view with a little form, when save button is pressed I send the data to the `TableView` controller to show it, also I'm using `NSUserDefaults` to save this data in an array.

My problem comes when, for example, I add 2 new rows and delete 1 of them, then when I add another, it shows the last row I delete instead of showing the one I just add.

I'm doing the saving and reading this way:

in `viewDidAppear` I read the `NSUserDefaults` and get the data if exist.
in the method that catches the data from the `ModalView` I save to userdefaults.
in `commitEditing` method I read userdefaults and then delete the row from the array and from the table and then save this change in userdefaults.

I don't know what I doing wrong, Can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Use `[self.tableView reloadData];` in the `viewWillAppear` of that class. You can also reference that class in another view controller, create an object for it and call `[classObject.tableView reloadData];`

Always remember to **reload the `tableView`** after an add operation or a delete operation.

Comment: I tried putting the [self.tableView reloadData]; in viewWillApperar but didn't work, it's gotta be something about the reloadData cuz when I go back and enter again to the tableview controller the row its updated with the last row I saved, i mean its showing everything well. I think the problem is only in the moment when I add the new row and the modal is dismissed. =S. Btw thanks for your quick answer XD

Answer (score 0):

Don’t use NSUserDefaults to act as the direct datasource of a table. Store it in an intermediate model. It’ll be a LOT easier to debug that way.

If you’re having trouble keeping your model synced with the user defaults, call `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize]` whenever you alter them.

Also, make sure you’re not making some mistakes in your table cell reuse. You might be seeing old data if you have a customer UITableViewCell class and you’re not correctly implementing `-prepareForReuse`.

Comment: Hi, David thanks for your time, I'm calling the sync method everytime I save and about the -prepareForReuse I hadn't heard about it so I searched a little and I found that its a method that resets values for custom cells, but I don't know what values have to be resest and when should I call this method. Can you tell me more about this pls ??.

Comment: It’s not to be called manually, it’s to be overridden by subclasses of UITableViewCell. If you’re not using any custom UITableViewCell subclasses, then that’s not the problem. If you want more help, you should post some code.